# New battery causes Dell XPS 17 to shut off during boot up

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

I have a Dell XPS 17 L1702X laptop running Windows 7.  The original battery will still take a charge, but only will give me about a half hour of operation before it needs to be charged again.  Other than the short life, I have no problems with the original battery.

I ordered two new batteries thru Amazon that are identical to the original.  These new batteries both will take a full charge, but when I run the computer only on battery power, during the startup routine the computer shuts off.  I have to remove and reinstall the battery before it will even turn on when I press the power button, and then it shuts off again.

I have run a diagnostic check on both new batteries and both checked out good.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What brand of battery?

Comment: The new batteries are Dell OEM.

Comment: Strange issue, scratch head...where exactly during startup does it shut down?

Comment: Just because they say they are Dell doesn't meant they are actual Dell batteries sadly the only guaranteed way to get Dell batteries is through Dell.  My suggestion return them to the sell has defective.  If you got a "discount" larger then 10% be suspect of how official these batteries are.  Companies are known to make "fake" batteries, and put official logos, all the real and fake products are all produced in the same place normally but the fake product is extremely cheap